# How do the two sets of parameters in the Coordinate Operation processing tool interact?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

QGIS' modeler provides a "Coordinate Operation" processing tool as model input. One can use it to specify the exact coordinate operation a transformation/reprojection will use.

The [documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.24/core/QgsProcessingParameterCoordinateOperation.html#qgis.core.QgsProcessingParameterCoordinateOperation) says

> A coordinate operation parameter for processing algorithms, for selection between available coordinate operations to use when projecting between a source and destination coordinate reference system.

When added to a model it shows four main parameters in the dialog:

- Source CRS parameter
- Destination CRS parameter
- Static source CRS
- Static destination CRS

[image]

The first two parameters can be set to get their values from CRS or layer nodes. The second two can be used to select CRS when creating the model. I assume that this is their intent, dynamic selection via user input for the first two, fixed values decided by the model creator for the latter. But what happens if both are filled? Which one is the parameter actually used in the end if both are set?

My question is: How do these two sets of parameters interact?

I am interested in QGIS 3.24 or later.

Comment: Hi! Can you include the QGIS version in the question?

Comment: Sure thing, 3.24 or later.